# My heroku app isn't getting the postgresDB on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql, heroku

I deployed a React app on heroku and also adde postgres module, but I am not getting any data on the frontend, while I can modify everything from the console in the backend.

my code:

```
// this is the DB config:

const { text } = require("express");
let pg = require("pg");
if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
  pg.defaults.ssl = true;
}

// include an OR statement if you switch between a local dev db and
// a remote heroku environment

let connString =
  process.env.DATABASE_URL ||
  process.env.PG_HOST;
const { Pool } = require("pg");

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: connString,
});

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
};
```

```
// this is the axios config

import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL + '/api/v1/restaurants',

})
```

when I log the DATABASE_URL variable, I get undefined. please HELP!

Comment: Is the `DATABASE_URL` added to the config vars section in your Heroku app? You can check it in the Settings page of your Heroku dashboard.

Comment: Harshana Serasinghe, yes it is, looks more or less like this: ```postgres://<data>:<another_data>42987404ec@ec2-23-20-168-40.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d24qet9lga6fnu```